# Why does my second sendinput not actually send input?

Tags: c++, windows

So the issue is with line 46, the `sendinput` of the keyboard within the `if` statement, the `cout` will execute within the `if` statement, however the `sendinput` never seems to work. The `sendinput` of the keyboard will work by itself, as will the mouse `sendinput`, and will both work in this program if the position of them is swapped i.e. the keyboard `sendinput` activates every 1 second whilst the mouse `sendinput` is every 10, however they won't work in the given order.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

bool on = true;
//numpad1 for off
void onoff() {
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD1)) {

            on = !on;

    }
}
int main() {

    INPUT keyB;
    keyB.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    keyB.ki.wVk = VK_F1;
    keyB.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    keyB.ki.time = 0;
    keyB.ki.wScan = 0;
    keyB.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    INPUT input;
    input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    input.mi.dx = 0;
    input.mi.dy = 0;
    input.mi.dwFlags = (MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP);
    input.mi.mouseData = 0;
    input.mi.dwExtraInfo = NULL;
    input.mi.time = 0;

    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    while (1) {
        if (on) {
            SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
              std::cout << "ON";

              std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

            if (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(end - begin).count() >= 10) {
                SendInput(1, &keyB, sizeof(INPUT));
                std::cout << "f1";
                begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
            }
            Sleep(1000);
            onoff();
        }
        else {

            std::cout << "OFF";
            Sleep(1000);
            onoff();
            begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        }
    }
}
```

edit:
as per a suggestion in the comments, the return value of the `SendInput` is 1, whilst `GetLastError()` returns 0

Comment: You should check the return value of `SendInput` and you should call `GetLastError` to find out the reason for any failure. It may not tell you anything useful, but it's easy to do, and should be your first step.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions, the return value was 1, and the error return was 0

Comment: A return value of 1 means that the call succeeded. I said it might not be helpful! Sorry I don't have any more suggestions.

Comment: Your code works with me with Notepad on Windows 7. However, I must put the mouse cursor in a position where right-clicking the mouse does not open a popup window (such as the window border), because as long as a popup window is open, pressing F1 has no effect (even when pressed with a real keyboard).

Comment: oh interesting, I guess it must be that when both are placed in the while loop, the instant execution of them both is not enough time for the right click to have effect, and thus the f1 key has an effect

Comment: @sb99: In the code you posted, the right-click is sent immediately before the F1 keypress. Therefore, the right-click does have an effect in that it opens up a popup menu in Notepad, thereby making the subsequent F1 keypress have no effect (because the popup menu is open).

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code to include 2 seperate timers and I moved some Sleeps around to give it time to detect the right click before the F1 key press.  It will do a mouse press every 500 milliseconds, and a F1 key press every 500 milliseconds.  Only issue is the Sleeps in between the code change the delays a bit, so keep that in mind when you setup your timing.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{

    INPUT input;
    input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    input.mi.dx = 0;
    input.mi.dy = 0;
    //input.mi.dwFlags = (MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP);
    input.mi.mouseData = 0;
    input.mi.dwExtraInfo = NULL;
    input.mi.time = 0;

    INPUT keyB;
    keyB.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    keyB.ki.wVk = VK_F1;
    keyB.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    keyB.ki.time = 0;
    keyB.ki.wScan = 0;
    keyB.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    using Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> start, start2, now;
    std::chrono::milliseconds duration, duration2;

    Sleep(500); //gives you time to move your mouse over to notepad

    start = now = Clock::now();

    while (1)
    {
        now = Clock::now();
        duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now - start);
        duration2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now - start2);

        if (duration.count() >= 500)
        {
            input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN;
            SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));

            Sleep(20);

            input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP;
            SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));

            std::cout << "Mouse Btn Right\n";
            start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        }

        Sleep(20);

        if (duration2.count() >= 10)
        {
            SendInput(1, &keyB, sizeof(INPUT));
            std::cout << "F1\n";
            start2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]